# Group by and count with condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, data-transform

I have a dataset, looks like this:

| id | DateTx | TypeTx | Major_complaint | Grade_major |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 3 |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 3 |
| 1 | 08/02/2021 | Reflexology | Pain | 4 |
| 1 | 15/02/2021 | Reflexology | Pain | 3 |
| 1 | 17/12/2020 | Nutrition counseling | Depression | 4 |
| 1 | 24/02/2021 | Reflexology | Pain | 3 |
| 2 | 07/10/2020 | Acupuncture | Neuropathy legs | 5 |
| 2 | 21/10/2020 | Acupuncture | Neuoropathic pain | 4 |
| 3 | 18/01/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 4 |
| 3 | 23/02/2021 | Reflexology | Neuropathy legs | 4 |
| 3 | 31/01/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 4 |

I want to make group by id, TypeTx, First and Last date of Tx, and Grades(first and last), So I expect received like this:

| id | FirstDateTx | LastDateTx | TypeTx | Major_complaint | First_Grade | Last_Grade | CountTx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2021 | 01/03/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 08/02/2021 | 15/02/2021 | Reflexology | Pain | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 17/12/2020 | 17/12/2020 | Nutrition counseling | Depression | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 07/10/2020 | 07/10/2020 | Acupuncture | Neuropathy legs | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 21/10/2020 | 21/10/2020 | Acupuncture | Neuoropathic pain | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 18/01/2021 | 31/01/2021 | Reflexology | Fatigue / exhaustion | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 23/02/2021 | 23/02/2021 | Reflexology | Neuropathy legs | 4 | 4 | 1 |

I try dplyr:

```
Tal_data %>% 
group_by(id) %>% mutate(DateTxStart=min(DateTx), 
                        DateTxEnd=max(DateTx),
                        First_grade= first(Grade_major),
                        Last_grade=last(Grade_major)) %>% 
count(TypeTx, DateTxStart, DateTxEnd, First_grade,Last_grade, Major_complaint)
```

So I get like this:

[image]

As you can see I cant link grade to date and typeTx. For example for id=1, nutrion counseling , depression grade must be 4, not 3 as in my solution
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dput of data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L), DateTx = c("01/02/2021", "01/03/2021", "08/02/2021", "15/02/2021", 
    "17/12/2020", "24/02/2021", "07/10/2020", "21/10/2020", "18/01/2021", 
    "23/02/2021", "31/01/2021"), TypeTx = c("Reflexology", "Reflexology", 
      "Reflexology", "Reflexology", "Nutrition counseling", "Reflexology", 
      "Acupuncture", "Acupuncture", "Reflexology", "Reflexology", "Reflexology"
    ), Major_complaint = c("Fatigue / exhaustion", "Fatigue / exhaustion", 
      "Pain", "Pain", "Depression", "Pain", "Neuropathy legs", "Neuoropathic pain", 
      "Fatigue / exhaustion", "Neuropathy legs", "Fatigue / exhaustion"
    ), Grade_major = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DateTx = lubridate::dmy(DateTx)) %>%
  arrange(id, DateTx) %>%
  group_by(id, TypeTx, Major_complaint) %>%
  summarise(FirstDateTx = first(DateTx), 
    LastDateTx = last(DateTx), 
    First_Grade = first(Grade_major), 
    Last_Grade = last(Grade_major), 
    CountTx = n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id', 'TypeTx'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 7 x 8
#> # Groups:   id, TypeTx [4]
#>      id TypeTx    Major_complaint  FirstDateTx LastDateTx First_Grade Last_Grade
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr>            <date>      <date>           <int>      <int>
#> 1     1 Nutritio… Depression       2020-12-17  2020-12-17           4          4
#> 2     1 Reflexol… Fatigue / exhau… 2021-02-01  2021-03-01           3          3
#> 3     1 Reflexol… Pain             2021-02-08  2021-02-24           4          3
#> 4     2 Acupunct… Neuoropathic pa… 2020-10-21  2020-10-21           4          4
#> 5     2 Acupunct… Neuropathy legs  2020-10-07  2020-10-07           5          5
#> 6     3 Reflexol… Fatigue / exhau… 2021-01-18  2021-01-31           4          4
#> 7     3 Reflexol… Neuropathy legs  2021-02-23  2021-02-23           4          4
#> # … with 1 more variable: CountTx <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Yeap, its work, so I needed arrange and more factors in group_by function. Thank you